# Inserting a csv with multirow using csvsimple

Tags: csvsimple

I would like to read the following table with the values from the first column joined in a multirow.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{my_data.csv}
    category, a, b
    A,0,1
    A,2,1,
    B,1,1
    B,0,0
    B,2,1
\end{filecontents*}
```

Here is the output that I would like to obtain :

[image: expected result]

I have tried reading naively with `csvsimple`, but the first row is missing, the values from the first column are repeated and I don't know how to add the `\hlines` after each change of category.

Should I change the format of my table or is it possible to read this csv and obtain a similar result to Table 1?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}



\begin{filecontents*}{my_data.csv}
    category, a, b
    A,0,1
    A,2,1,
    B,1,1
    B,0,0
    B,2,1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|cc}
         category&a&b  \\
         \multirow{2}{*}{A}&0&1\\ 
                            &2&1\\\hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{B}&1&1\\
                          &0&0\\
                          &2&1\\
                            
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Expected output}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|cc}
    category&a&b\\
\csvreader[head to column names]{my_data.csv}{}{\\\csvcoli&\csvcolii&\csvcoliii}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{my attempt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]